# Trying to use Graph API to get user's channels and post messages to MS Teams Channel from Web App

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to write a web app on our website which gets a User's MS Team channels and then posts a message to a channel of their choosing using MS Teams Graph API.

I'm about to get an access token using the OAuth API, and I'm passing access token (AAD token) to the /me/joinedTeams endpoint, it's giving me the below error:

{
"error": {
"code": "ResourceNotFound",
"message": "Resource not found.",
"innerError": {
"date": "2021-05-14T20:57:03",
"request-id": "30d80d9a-66f4-47ff-ab11-dacb7f817806",
"client-request-id": "30d80d9a-66f4-47ff-ab11-dacb7f817806"
}
}
}

[Screenshot of my Graph Explorer results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8aYV.png)

UPDATE:

I have gotten my account converted to a Work account, and added the permissions. Now I am getting this response/error:

[Screenshot of new Graph Explorer results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2WEB.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's better for you to share how to get an access token using the OAuth API. In this issue , it seems your signed-in user is a personal Microsoft account, that's not supported to access the `/me/joinedTeams` endpoint. [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) of this API.

[image]

**There are some notes here:**

1. When using Graph Explorer, access token is here after login. You don't need to add bearer token in Request headers.

[image]

2. You have to sign in with a work or school account, and you need to consent one of the required permissions in "modify permissions(Preview)".

[image]

Comment: I've updated my question, as I've done what was requested, but still am unable to get access to the API end point. I've added a screenshot of the latest Graph response.

Comment: As the error shows, the signed-in user doesn't have Office365 license. Navigate to Azure AD > Users > select the user > Licenses > +Assignments
 in the portal.

Comment: Is there some way to do development without a corporate paid license? Although we are developing this feature for our users who will have corporate licenses, we currently, do not need a corporate license for our company or an Office365 license.

Comment: If you want to list joined teams with a signed-in user, the license is required. Another way for you is to use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token) with **application** permissions. `GET /users/{id}/joinedTeams`